# Two routes instantiate when "Registration" is triggered

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I have an app with a registration and a login flow. And I'm having bit of an issue with nested stack navigators when used with Redux.

**React-Navigation structure**

- RootNavigator (Stack navigator)

  - Registration (Stack navigator)
  - Login (Stack navigator)

**App setup**

- react: 16.0.0-alpha.6,
- react-native: 0.44.2,
- react-navigation: ^1.0.0-beta.11,
- react-redux: ^5.0.6,

My issue is that when 'Registration' (or 'Login') is triggered from 'Landing' ReactNavigation instantiate two initial screens for the nested (internal) stack navigator. Please see the screen grabs bellow.

**This is the landing state (which is correct)**
[image]

**But when 'Register' is pressed, this is what happens.**
[image]

I end up with two routes for 'Registration' (routeName is called 'PersonalRego'). As shown in the screen shot, **'Step1' is duplicated where as I was expecting to only have one 'Step1' instance in the routes array**. But the keys for those two 'Step1' are different. One starts with 'Init-' the other one doesn't.

As a result, navigating back (pressing 'Close' button on top) does not dismiss registration as per expectation. It rather shows the 'Step1' of registration again.

Other than this issue, everything with react-navigation seems to be workinf fine for me. Is there anything special that I need to do when configuring nested StackNavigators in a ReactNative + ReactNavigation + Redux app?

I'm a bit baffled by this. Any comments are gladly welcomed.

P.s : StackNavigator code (just one level deep nested StackNavigator)

```
// LandingNav.js

const routes = {
    Landing: { screen: Landing },
    PersonalRego: { screen: PersonalRego },
    Auth: { screen: Auth },
};

const config = {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRoute: 'Landing,
};
const Root = StackNavigator(routes, config);
```

.

```
// PersonalRegoNav.js
const routes = {
    Step1: { screen: Step1 },
    Step2: { screen: Step2 },
    Step3: { screen: Step3 },
};

const config = {
    headerMode: 'none,
    initialRoute: 'Step1',
};

const Root = StackNavigator(routes, config);
```

.

```
// AuthNav.js

const routes = {
    Login: { screen: LoginContainer },
    ForgotUsername: { screen: ForgotUsername },
    ForgotPassword: { screen: ForgotPassword },
};

const config = {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRoute: 'Login',
};
const Root = StackNavigator(routes, config);
```

Comment: Could you provide the code for both your navigators structure and how you use navigator to navigate?

Comment: @AlexanderVitanov : I've updated the question with my StackNav code structure. But the issue is unrelated to the structure. I was not calling the correct route name. Please refer to my own answer to this question for further info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question for posterity's sake.

When Register is pressed, I'm navigating to 'Step1' instead of 'PersonalRego'. 'PersonalRego' already has 'Step1' as an initial route, so if you navigate to 'Step1', it pushes another instance.

So calling 'PersonalRego' route on Register button press fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the link below, beautifully solved & explained by my friend -> https://medium.com/@kakul.gupta009/custom-drawer-using-react-navigation-80abbab489f7

Comment: That link says "Access denied". But I manage to fix my issue. Will explain in an answer.